# Allow Non-issued Security Certificate for Localhost Via Group Policy

Tags: security, ssl, group-policy, internet-explorer

I have an application at https://localhost:4321

When using Internet Explorer 8 I'm greated with a "There is a problem with this website's security certificate" message with the big red X etc...

Two options are presented: Click here to close the webpage, and Continue to this website (not reccommened)

Of course I want to continue to this website so I click that, and it goes to the webpage.

I want to get rid of this screen via group policy I have tried adding it to the intranet zone (via GPO), however this problem still persists. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry I do want it to trust on every computer in the domain so it has to be run through GPJ, I'm just not sure how best to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to trust it on every computer in the domain, or just the one that you're working on?

Since it's localhost and all, it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to do it through GPO - other nodes accessing this one would just have a name mismatch access a cert with a subject name of `localhost`, anyway.

So - if you want to use Group Policy to trust the cert, you certainly could.. but this might be easier.  Export the cert to a file from IE, then open it up.  There'll be an "Install Certificate" button - hit that, run through the wizard, and the cert will be permanently installed in your trusted certificates store (which you can verify in `certmgr.msc`).

Comment: Sorry I do want it to trust on every computer in the domain so it has to be run through GPJ, I'm just not sure how best to do it.

Comment: What's the subject name on the certificate, first of all?  If it's localhost, then you need to be creating a new certificate for trust on other nodes.